# Nested listeners that use notify-method with the same name

Tags: java, listener

I have three classes, A, B and C. A listens to B for changes, and B listens to C. If C is changed, it will call notifyChange() on it's listener, B, whose listening method looks like this:

```
clientComp.setChangeListener(new NavigationClientCompositeListener() {

        @Override
        public void notifyChange() {
            notifyChange();
        }
    });
```

B just wants to pass this notification on to A, and here lies my problem. the notifyChange() call inside the notifyChange() method, will cause an infinite loop. Is there a way to reference notifyChange()-method of the B class inside this interface-implementation? Or is this just bad design to begin with?

How can I best solve this problem? I could of course change the name of B's method, but that would make it ridicoulus if I have many nested classes like this and it's not the solution I'm after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `<class-name>.this` helps you refer to the current instance of outer class

```
clientComp.setChangeListener(new NavigationClientCompositeListener() {

    @Override
    public void notifyChange() {
        B.this.notifyChange(); //Calls the notifyChange() of B, which is the outer class
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When establishing this observer type behavior the observers should register with those they observe, this can be expressed with interfaces.

```
public interface Observable{
   public void registerObserver(Observer o);
}

public interface Observer{
   public void notify();
}
```

Then implement these interfaces in your respective classes.

```
class A implements Observer{
   public void notify(){
      //do something
   }
}

class B implements Observer, Observable{
   List<Observer> observers = new ArrayList<Observer>();
   public void notify(){
      for(Observer o: observers){
          o.notify();
      }
   }

   public void registerObserver(Observer o){
       observers.add(o);
   }
}

class C implements Observable{
   List<Observer> observers = new ArrayList<Observer>();

   public void registerObserver(Observer o){
       observers.add(o);
   }

   public void doSomething(){
      for(Observer o: observers){
          o.notify();
      }
   }
}
```

Then register these observers together in some method or main method:

```
A a = new A();
B b = new B();
C c = new C();
b.registerObserver(a);
c.registerObserver(b);
c.doSomething();
```

**Please note this is all psuedo code to illustrate a principle.  I cannot guarantee its compilation**